# Prove Cardinality of Sets Exponentiation

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am studying for an exam in elementary set theory and I am not understanding the proof for this theorem:

For any three sets $A,B,C$:

$(A^B)^C \sim A^{(B \times C)}$

I know I need to find a bijective function $G : (C\rightarrow A^B) \rightarrow (B\times C \rightarrow A)$.
But I don't have a clue.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $f\colon C\to A^B$. Define $\varphi(f)\colon B\times C\to A$ to be the function
$$
\varphi(f)\colon (b,c)\mapsto f(c)(b)
$$
(the value of $f(c)$ at $b$), which is a function $\varphi(f)\colon B\times C\to A$.

Let $g\colon B\times C\to A$; for $c\in C$, define $\psi(g)\colon C\to A^B$, by declaring that, for $c\in C$,
$$
\psi(g)(c)\colon b\mapsto g(b,c)
$$
so we have a function $\psi(g)\colon C\to A^B$.